# gwt generic page level click handler

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I have this situation, where I display a success/error message on a page and then I want it to disappear when the user does anything on the page (I assume that that triggers a click event, I can ignore events like going to new tab/windows etc.).

I have other "uihandlers" and "clickhandlers" on the page. So if I click empty regions on the page only the `hidemessage` call fires, else if I click valid 'clickable' elements my `hidemessage` fires first followed by the relevant handler.

Is there a way I can achieve this without adding `hidemessage` to all my clickhandlers on the page?

Edit: The message widget is not a `PopupPanel`, so `setAutohide(true)` won't work. But it is exactly the behavior I'm looking for. The widget is a custom widget which `extends Composite implements HasWidget, HasClickHandlers`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this on your error message:

```
myPopupPanel.setAutoHideEnabled(true);
```

It does exactly whet you need. You may also consider setting auto-hide on history events (mostly back button):

```
myPopupPanel.setAutoHideOnHistoryEventsEnabled(true);
```

EDIT:

If you are not using a PopupPanel, you can make your Widget implement EventPreview, and then:

```
public boolean onEventPreview(Event event) {

Element target = DOM.eventGetTarget(event);

boolean widgetIsTarget = (target != null) && DOM.isOrHasChild(getElement(), target);

setVisible(widgetIsTarget):
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that the message is not a ```PopupPanel``` but a custom widget which ```extends Composite implements HasWidget, HasClickHandlers```. But thanks for this!! Worst case, I'll see if I can implement my own autohide based on this. Edited the question

Comment: sorry for the delay. in my case it will nearly always be setvisible(false). so yes a variation of this works for me. thanks!!